# cannot install magento2.4 rom command line on Centos7

Tags: magento2

PHP7.4 + Nginx + Mysql are all installed.

Elasticsearch is already installed.

Downloaded the Magento 2.4 source code, magento-ce-2.4.0_sample_data-2020-07-26-02-51-57.tar.gz, unpacked it, and installed it on the command line with the following error.

[max@192 m24]$ ./bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://mag.dev/ \

> --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=hdqQP5%aBus3 
> --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com 
> --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US 
> --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 
> --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=192.168.10.46:8080 
> --elasticsearch-port=9200
> Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try "bin/magento setup:di:compile" command

Comment: [Progress: 739 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':

In PatchApplier.php line 170:

Comment: Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogSampleData for module Magento_CatalogSampleData. Origina  
  l exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.                                                                
                                                                                                                                                

In Mysql.php line 319:
                                                             
  Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.